# HDP Kafka schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

the schema registry developed by confluent, now pushed to open source, has it been adopted by Hortonworks HDP yet?

The answer I am expecting is

1. No HDP Kafka does not have schema registry capablities
2. Yes HDP has schema registry - the version is x.x
3. No but there is something similar to schema registry it is called "xxxx"

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer is 3

Look: https://hortonworks.com/blog/part-2-hdf-blog-series-shared-schema-registry-important/

Comparing the Github repositories both project have a different code base:

- https://github.com/hortonworks/registry
- https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry